# Comparing date object in a Couplet between two dates

Tags: python, algebraixlib

I am loading csv file using "import_csv". Suppose I have a file looks like below.

mycsvfile.csv:

```
col1, col2
1, date(01-01-2015)
```

and then I load this file using "import_csv" and results are following:

```
Set = Couplets('col1', '1'), Couplets('col2', 'date(01-01-2015)')
```

and now I want to check whether the right Couplet object (which is date) is between two dates say 01-01-2014 and 01-01-2016 and return false or true.

In other words if I have.

```
twodates = Set(Couplet('firstdate',read_date('1/1/2014')), Couplet('seconddate',read_date('1/1/2016')))
print(twodates)

onedate = Couplet('twodates', read_date('1/1/2015'))
```

I want to check whether onedate right couplet is between two right couplets dates of twodates couplets.

Please let me know if you need more explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the `import`s I used and some sample CSV data. (You should be able to copy/paste and execute the following code).

```
from datetime import datetime, date
from io import StringIO
from algebraixlib.io.csv import import_csv
from algebraixlib.mathobjects import Set, Couplet
import algebraixlib.algebras.sets as sets
import algebraixlib.algebras.clans as clans

# Sample CSV as a string
mycsvfile = """col1,col2
1,date(01-01-2015)
2,date(01-01-2018)
3,date(04-01-2015)"""
```

First, import the CSV date information as Python date objects, rather than strings.

```
def read_date(date_str: str) -> datetime:
    return datetime.strptime(date_str, 'date(%m-%d-%Y)').date()

# The read_date helper imports the date(...) strings as Python date objects
data_clan = import_csv(StringIO(mycsvfile), {'col1': int, 'col2': read_date})
```

Here is the data algebra translation (as a clan):

```
{{('col1'->1), ('col2'->datetime.date(2015, 1, 1))}, {('col1'->2), ('col2'->datetime.date(2018, 1, 1))}, {('col1'->3), ('col2'->datetime.date(2015, 4, 1))}}
```

Here's a function `record_in_range` that returns `True` if a record (as a relation) is within the date range. Note: Every relation in this clan is a function from left->right; this enables the `rel(left_value)` syntax.

```
assert clans.is_functional(data_clan)

def record_in_range(rel):
    date_value = rel('col2').value  # .value extracts the raw literal from the Atom
    return date(2014, 1, 1) < date_value < date(2016, 1, 1)
```

This can be paired with the `sets.restrict` operation to filter your clan down to just records that are within the range.

```
only_in_range = sets.restrict(data_clan, record_in_range)
print(only_in_range)
```

Output:

```
{{('col1'->1), ('col2'->datetime.date(2015, 1, 1))}, {('col1'->3), ('col2'->datetime.date(2015, 4, 1))}}
```

In your question, you had encoded the date range in a relation `twodates`. The following code pulls the date values from there, rather than hardcoding them in the `record_in_range` function.

```
twodates = Set(Couplet('firstdate', date(2014, 1, 1)), Couplet('seconddate', date(2016, 1, 1)))

def between_two_dates(rel):
    return twodates('firstdate').value < rel('col2').value < twodates('seconddate').value

only_in_range = sets.restrict(data_clan, between_two_dates)
print(only_in_range)
```

Output is the same as above.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @van  for the benefit of future readers, remember to accept the answer if it is correct :)