# Writing complex query using algebraixlib

Tags: python, algebraixlib

I am trying to accomplish some complex ETL (Extract, Transfer, Load) process using algebraixlib. I have a query something like this

```
Select column1, column2, column3, column4, date(column5), date(column6) 
FROM mytable 
WHERE column1 = some string,
AND a date value = between column5 and column6,
AND (column3 = some string OR Comunn3 = some other string),
AND (column4 = some string OR Comunn4 = some other string)
```

The more complex part for me is to write `OR` and `AND` operations nested with each other so for example in line `AND (column3 = some string OR Comunn3 = some other string)`, I don't know how to write an `OR` operation followed by an `AND` operation and then continue again with `AND` and so on. I know that `clans.superstrict` can be used for `AND` and `OR` operations. But nested `AND` `OR` operations I can not figure it out.

Is it possible that somebody could help me putting all this together in one function using `algebraixlib`. I have also read the book but it did not help much in this matter.

Please let me know if you need more explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Setup

Here is some example code and explanation that models the `where` clause in algebraixlib. Here are the Python imports to make the code run:

```
from datetime import datetime, date
from io import StringIO
from algebraixlib.io.csv import import_csv
from algebraixlib.mathobjects import Set, Couplet, Atom
import algebraixlib.algebras.sets as sets
import algebraixlib.algebras.clans as clans
from algebraixlib.algebras.relations import is_functional
```

Here is an example CSV file that has the columns that are mentioned in the query, along with the code to import it as a clan. (Relates to answer given in [comparing-date-object-in-a-couplet-between-two-dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32653374/comparing-date-object-in-a-couplet-between-two-dates)). The column names are abbreviated.

```
mycsvfile = """col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6
foo,bar1,baz1,nurf1,date(01-01-2015),date(01-01-2016)
foo,bar2,baz2,nurf2,date(01-02-2015),date(01-02-2016)
foo,bar3,baz2,nurf3,date(01-03-2015),date(01-03-2016)
foo,bar4,baz3,nurf2,date(01-04-2015),date(01-04-2016)
notfoo,bar5,baz1,nurf1,date(01-05-2015),date(01-05-2016)
foo,bar6,baz1,nurf2,date(01-06-2998),date(01-06-2999)"""

def read_date(date_str: str) -> datetime:
    return datetime.strptime(date_str, 'date(%m-%d-%Y)').date()

# The read_date helper imports the date(...) strings as Python date objects
data_clan = import_csv(StringIO(mycsvfile),
                       {'col1': str, 'col2': str, 'col3': str, 'col5': read_date, 'col6': read_date})
```

Here is your SQL, rewritten with specific constants.

```sql
select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6
from mytable
where column1 = 'foo',
and date(04-01-2015) between col5 and col6,
and (col3 = 'baz1' or col3 = 'baz2')
and (col4 = 'nurf1' or col4 = 'nurf2')
```

### Method #1: Restrict by a Predicate

Since algebraixlib is a Python package, its fairly easy to construct a complex predicate using the built-in logical operators and wrapping that up in a function that is passed to `clans.restrict`. `custom_predicate` takes a single relation (an element of `data_clan`) as its input and returns a `bool`.

```
def custom_predicate(rel):
    assert is_functional(rel)
    return rel('col1') == Atom('foo') \
           and rel('col5') < Atom(date(2015, 4, 1)) < rel('col6') \
           and (rel('col3') == Atom('baz1') or rel('col3') == Atom('baz2')) \
           and (rel('col4') == Atom('nurf1') or rel('col4') == Atom('nurf2'))
answer = sets.restrict(data_clan, custom_predicate)
```

This returns the following clan `MathObject` (printed in table form):

```
'col1'|'col2'|'col3'|'col4' |'col5'                   |'col6'                   |
'foo' |'bar1'|'baz1'|'nurf1'|datetime.date(2015, 1, 1)|datetime.date(2016, 1, 1)|
'foo' |'bar2'|'baz2'|'nurf2'|datetime.date(2015, 1, 2)|datetime.date(2016, 1, 2)|
```

### Method #2 - Use Superstriction

Your question hinted at a more data algebra-centric way of modeling the equality tests in the `where` clause.

> I know that clans.superstrict can be used for AND and OR operations.
>   But nested AND OR operations I can not figure it out.

You can turn your predicate (the equality parts) into a clan in disjunctive normal form where each relation is `or`'d together and each couplet is `and`'d together. This isn't as bad as it sounds. Consider each of the conjunctions in your query as a singleton clan that describes possible values for given column:

[image]

The set of disjunctions we're looking for is given by taking the cross union of these clans.

[image]

Now superstricting `data_clan` with *predAsClan* leaves only the records with strings that match the `where` clause. The date range part can then be handled with a simpler predicate function. Here it is in code:

```
vals_col1 = Set(Set(Couplet('col1', 'foo')))
vals_col3 = Set(Set(Couplet('col3', 'baz1')), Set(Couplet('col3', 'baz2')))
vals_col4 = Set(Set(Couplet('col4', 'nurf1')), Set(Couplet('col4', 'nurf2')))
pred_as_clan = clans.cross_union(vals_col1, clans.cross_union(vals_col3, vals_col4))
answer = clans.superstrict(data_clan, pred_as_clan)
answer = sets.restrict(answer, lambda rel: rel('col5') < Atom(date(2015, 4, 1)) < rel('col6'))
```

Gives the same answer:

```
'col1'|'col2'|'col3'|'col4' |'col5'                   |'col6'                   |
'foo' |'bar1'|'baz1'|'nurf1'|datetime.date(2015, 1, 1)|datetime.date(2016, 1, 1)|
'foo' |'bar2'|'baz2'|'nurf2'|datetime.date(2015, 1, 2)|datetime.date(2016, 1, 2)|
```

Comment: thank you :) I prefer the second approach better since it is algebraic way. @wesholler could you confirm that clans are cached by algebraixlib or do I have to especially cache them ?

Comment: @van - You're welcome! Currently algebraixlib does not automatically cache data or expressions (as described in the book). However, all `MathObject`s are hashable and thus suitable for use in Python collections like `dict` and `set`.